# Populate Python dictionaries with pre-assigned keys and values of a particular length

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Say for example I have the following dictionary in Python:

```
memory_map = {'data': [1,2,3], 'theta': [4,5,6,7]}
```

I would like to create another random dictionary that is identical to `memory_map`, has the same keys and the same lengths of lists as their values however the elements of the list are populated with random values using the `np.random.default_rng(seed).uniform(low, high, size)` function.

An example would be: `random_dict = {'data': [5,3,1], 'theta': [7,3,4,8]}`.

Moreover, if the names of the keys or the lengths of the lists in values change, this should automatically be reflected in the `random_dict` that is created.

If I add a new key or remove a key from the `memory_map` this should also be reflected in the `random_dict`.

So far, I have `random_dict = {item: [] for item in list(memory_map.keys())}` but am unsure of how to populate the empty list with the random values of the same length.

Thanks.

Comment: `import random`; `random_dict = {k: [random.randint(1, 9) for _ in v] for k, v in memory_map.items()}`

Comment: So if you add a new key to memory map it should add a new key to random_dict?

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far. Looks like a fairly simple problem and can be solved with loop.

Comment: I have added some more info to the question and also what I have tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this.

```
import random
import itertools


def shuffle_map(input_map):
    # Grab a list of all values
    all_values = list(itertools.chain(*input_map.values()))
    random.shuffle(all_values)  # Shuffle it

    new_map = {}  # Initialize a new map
    i = 0  # Keep track of how many items we've consumed
    for key, value in input_map.items():
        n = len(value)  # How many values per this key
        new_map[key] = all_values[i : i + n]  # Assign a slice
        i += n

    return new_map


memory_map = {"data": [1, 2, 3], "theta": [4, 5, 6, 7]}
print(shuffle_map(memory_map))
```

This prints out (e.g., consecutive runs)

```
{'data': [1, 5, 7], 'theta': [2, 4, 3, 6]}
{'data': [6, 7, 1], 'theta': [5, 4, 3, 2]}
{'data': [5, 2, 3], 'theta': [7, 6, 4, 1]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What if I wanted to populate the lists using `np.random.default_rng(seed).uniform(low, high, size)`?

Answer (score 0):

For the random lists you should take a look at the `random` module in the standard library, specifically at the `random.sample` or `random.choices`, depending on your needs.
For the second request, of automatically update the dictionary based on changes of the first, the easiest way to do it is to create a wrapper around the first dict inheriting from the `collections.UserDict` class

Comment: You don't need to inherit from `UserDict` to subclass a dict.

Comment: yep, probably inheriting from dict it's just easier